# Admbo Adview rotates unwanted on LG L9

Tags: android, canvas, rotation

I have a big problem.

Im using a View in FrameLayout which I rotate with canvas.rotate. But on LG L9 my Adview also rotates in the same direction and it shouldnt rotate.
On Xpera Mini St15i it doesnt rotate.

Android is so buggy.

Im using normal OnDraw method in my CustomView

Heres my XML file

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:opencv="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
       xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <com.example.easymeasure.CustomOpenCVJavaCameraView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:id="@+id/OpenCVView"
        opencv:show_fps="false"
        opencv:camera_id="any" />

    <com.example.easymeasure.CustomView
        android:id="@+id/CustomView"  
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    />
    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout_camera_calibration" 
        android:visibility="gone"
        >
        <Button
                android:id="@+id/Button_cancel_camera_calibration"  
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/Button_cancel_camera_calibration"
                android:layout_gravity="left|bottom"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:onClick="Button_cancel_quick_hardware_test_onclick"                             
                />
        <Button
                android:id="@+id/Button_start_camera_calibration"  
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:text="@string/Button_start_camera_calibration"
                android:layout_gravity="right|bottom"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:onClick="Button_start_quick_hardware_test_onclick"                              
                />

    </LinearLayout>
    <RelativeLayout          
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
                         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                         android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                         android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                         android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                         ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3227530058034046/1468436616"
                         ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"/>
    </RelativeLayout>



</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found out how to solve the problem. I had to move my AdView in xml file before the CustomView with the Ondraw method. Anyway I think this behaviour isnt normal.

Edit:
Now Ive found out that other Frames are also moving if they laying above the CustomView in hierarchy. Until now I cant explain why there moving and how to remove this behaviour in Frames laying on top of the hirarchy.

Edit2: 
Ive found out whats causing this undefined behaviour. It happens if canvas.restore() gets more often called than canvas.save()